# How to use long integers in Python to build a range?

Tags: python

I am trying to build a range with an upper bound bigger than limit of integer in Python. I was looking for something like the following:

```
import sys
start = 100;
step = 100;
limit = sys.maxint + 1;
result = xrange(start, limit, step);
```

However, `xrange` parameters are limited to the integer. According to [Python Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange), I have to use `itertools` module: `islice(count(start, step), (stop-start+step-1)//step)`, but `islice` seems to have the same integer limitations for the parameters.

Is there any other way to build the list with upper limit represented by long integer?

Comment: You don't have to use semicolons at the end of lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`xrange` is trivial to roll out on your own, so you can do just that:

```
def xlongrange(start, limit, step):
    n = start
    while n < limit:
        yield n
        n += step
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for some standard function, so overlooked writing my own solution.

Comment: Doesn't work with negative step. Goes into infinite loop if step == 0 and start < limit.

Comment: Writing a formal spec, supporting negative step and adding argument checking is left as an exercise for the reader ;)